# Load classes from a jar file from a url to memory and then run the main class out of all the classes

Tags: java, class, url, jar, load

I'm trying to load classes from a jar file from a URL into memory then run one of the classes loaded.  I don't want the class files or the jar to ever be accessible by the user.  I've seen a couple similar questions, but they have gone unanswered.

I know it will probably use URLClassLoader and ByteArrayInputStream/ByteArrayOutputStream.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Similar unanswered questions:

[How to load a jar from an URL without downloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751584/how-to-load-a-jar-from-an-url-without-downloading-it)

[Load jar from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481852/load-jar-from-url)

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964076/how-to-load-classes-from-jar-file-in-memory-stream ... though it doesn't answer your "how to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track (I think).  The steps would be:

1. Use URLConnection to open a stream to the JAR file.
2. Read the stream and write it to ByteArrayOutputStream, and extract the  byte array.
3. Open a ByteArrayInputStream on the byte array, then wrap that in a JarInputStream.
4. Iterate through the members of the entries of the JAR file, saving the entry information and buffering the entry file content in memory.
5. Write a custom class loader that uses the in-memory cache of the JAR file entries and content.

I can't point you at example code because I couldn't find any.

(You pretty much have to cache stuff in memory since the `JarFile` API requires a `RandomAccessFile` and that implies that the data is in the file-system.  On some systems you could create a temporary file, open a RAF on it, unlink it, and then fetch and write the URL into the RAF.  But that isn't portable ...)

---

I should point out that if you are doing this as part of some licensing or "intellectual property management" scheme, you are probably wasting your time.  Any practical scheme that you care to implement in client-side code (i.e. code that runs on the user's machine) can be broken ... unless the machine is totally locked down.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.  In response to your last comment, does adding that the jar can only be accessed if a server-side auth-code and ip are matched change anything or is that still easily breakable?  Also what's the best method you'd suggest?  Doesn't have to be 100% fool-proof obviously since even professional programs are cracked. --- On a side note, would it be a lot easier to just allow the users to load obfuscated class files from the jar temporarily but directly?

Comment: It is still easily breakable. Seriously. I would suggest that you completely abandon the idea of keeping stuff secret on the users machine. Obfuscate your code if you have to ... to keep the boss happy ... but don't waste your time on more elaborate schemes. If you have "secret sauce" stuff, do it / keep it in a properly secured server.

Comment: For me I use a similiar method. I load over SSL and while obfuscated. It at least prevents easy reverse engineering on the parts of the game that check file hashes. The rest of the game on disk is a mix of obfuscation and not. Helps make it confusing for reconstruction of the internals and networking.  I also keep a SSL connection for all but time sensitive game data. The proxies still checks for cheating and integrity though.