# Execute file (exe) by a command in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I need that PostgreSQL run the .jar file that is saved to a bytea field in a table . At any given time a function is called and then the .jar file must be opened in the same way as if there was a double-clicking the file.

Is that possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. The function (whatever you mean with that) will run on the server. And the Postgres server process has no idea how to run that .jar file. And even if it did, it would be running on the server which most probably wouldn't help you either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the jar on the *client side*, there's no way to do this from the PostgreSQL server.

You can do this with a wrapper application in Java that is run on the client. It would:

- Connect to PostgreSQL, say using PgJDBC
- Query the database to get the bytea data for the jar
- [Instantiate a chain classloader that loads classes from the jar in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17872180/398670)
- Invoke the entrypoint method in the jar's main class

It's not going to be simple. If you don't mind saving the jar to a tempfile you can make it a bit simpler:

- Connect to PostgreSQL
- Query the database to get the bytea for the jar
- Save the jar data to a temporary file
- Run `javaw.exe \path\to\temp\file` to run the jar via an external process start, like `ProcessBuilder`.

You can do this in any language with a PostgreSQL driver.

If you can't even install a PostgreSQL driver, you could write a small C executable and bundle it with `libpq` to do this. Or even write a Powershell script that does it by running `psql`.